# Laravel 4: where's the profiler?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I used to be able to enable the profiler using the `profiler` property in `/application/config/application.php`.

It's no longer there. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Probably the **most complete profiler** package as of december 2013 :

**Laravel Debugbar** : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 8):

It isn't there anymore, although I have heard rumors that DayleRees may be trying to implement it again.

Comment: Just to add a bit to this. While there is no profiler, if you are wanting to see what queries are run or the time they run in you can listen to the illuminate.query event.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a profiler based on the old profiler: 
https://packagist.org/packages/loic-sharma/profiler

Comment: I suggest this one if you are looking for a profiler that looks and behaves exactly like the Laravel 3 profiler.

Comment: Yes, but since then, I created https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar so I would obviously recommend that one instead, as mentioned in other answers :)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Barry's suggestion of ioic-sharma/profiler there is an alternative written by juy which has a few more (in my opinion, after using both) useful features available for composer install here https://github.com/juy/profiler

edit: 19th Jan 2014: Seeing as the alternative I mentioned above is now in a perpetual state of abandonment, I would recommend the debug bar by barryvdh as found here:  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar its the one we in the office use in production.

Comment: **In the meantime the juy/profiler is abandoned.** [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) is suggested by _juy_ to be used in place of his profiler.